# Calcular quanto tempo demora pra executar uma função

Tags: javascript, desempenho

Tenho que criar uma função em `JavaScript` que pega todas os id's de uma tabela e faz um sorteio com id's da mesma tabela de modo que um mesmo id não caia com ele mesmo, e que haja a possibilidade que esse id possa estar na outra "casa".

exps:

```
1|2 - 2|1... válido.
1|1 - 2|2... inválido.
```

Desse modo:

```js
var teste = [];

for (var i = 1; i <= 305; i++) {
 for (var x = 1; x <= 305; x++) {
        if(x != i){
            teste.push(i+'|'+x);
        }
    }
}
console.log(teste)
```

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de saber quanto tempo que essa função demora pra executar, visto que ela gera mais de 90 mil registros.

Comment: Você quer medir o tempo de execução ou estimar antes de rodar?

Comment: medir o tempo de execução de acordo com a máquina do cliente, mas ter uma estimativa tbm viria bem a calhar rs

Comment: Uma pergunta +- off-topic, uma função que gera +- 90mil registros e que leva 27ms pode ser considerada lenta?

Comment: Eu não consideraria lenta, especialmente em se tratando de JavaScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para medir o tempo de execução, com resolução de milissegundos, basta comparar o timestamp antes de depois da execução:

```js
function fn() {
    var teste = [];
    
    for (var i = 1; i <= 305; i++) {
     for (var x = 1; x <= 305; x++) {
            if(x != i){
                teste.push(i+'|'+x);
            }
        }
    }
}
var antes = Date.now();
fn();
var duracao = Date.now() - antes;
document.body.innerHTML = "levou " + duracao + "ms";
```

Caso seu browser não dê suporte ao [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) (por exemplo, IE8 ou anterior), basta usar `new Date().getTime()`.

Quanto a estimar o tempo que levaria, antes de executar, aí eu já não sei a resposta. O que dá para estimar é o nível de complexidade, mas o tempo de execução vai depender de vários fatores, não sei se é possível.

Comment: nível de complexidade o(n^2) rs, `for` encadeado

Answer (score 9):

Para medir o tempo de execução você pode usar **[performance.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)**, exemplo:

```js
var teste = [];
var inicio = performance.now();
for (var i = 1; i <= 305; i++) {
 for (var x = 1; x <= 305; x++) {
        if(x != i){
           teste.push(i+'|'+x);
        }
    }
}
   
var fim = performance.now();
console.log(teste)
alert('Tempo de excução: ' + (fim - inicio));
```

Outra opção é **[console.time()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time)**, exemplo:

```js
var teste = [];
console.time('tempo');
for (var i = 1; i <= 305; i++) {
 for (var x = 1; x <= 305; x++) {
        if(x != i){
            teste.push(i+'|'+x);
        }
    }
}
console.timeEnd('tempo');
console.log(teste)
```

Comment: Esse objeto `performance`, é muito interessante, não o conhecia. +1 pelo novo conhecimento.

Comment: Complemento: `console.time` não é padrão do W3C, e o objeto performance pode não estar disponível dependendo de browser + versão. Então fica a dica da minha resposta, `new Date().getTime()` é a solução mais compatível.

Answer (score 1):

O próprio JavaScript tem [uma função pra isso](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/console/time) que seria o `console.time(label)`.

No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```js
var teste = [];

console.time();
for (var i = 1; i <= 305; i++) {
    for (var x = 1; x <= 305; x++) {
        if(x != i){
            teste.push(i+'|'+x);
        }
    }
}
console.timeEnd();

console.log(teste)
```

Mas, supondo que você queira testar com mais de um caso, poderia adicionar uma `label` para cada teste, assim:

```js
var teste = [];

console.time("timer principal");
for (var i = 1; i <= 305; i++) {
    console.time(`timer ${i}`);
    for (var x = 1; x <= 305; x++) {
        if(x != i){
            teste.push(i+'|'+x);
        }
    }
    console.timeEnd(`timer ${i}`);
}
console.timeEnd("timer principal");

console.log(teste)
```