# Como cronometrar o tempo até uma função terminar?

Tags: javascript

Quero cronometrar o tempo até todo o programa terminar o seu processo, preciso desse tempo para questão de comparação.
Existe algum modo fácil de implementar isso?

Comment: relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55867/calcular-quanto-tempo-demora-pra-executar-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim:

```
console.time('teste');
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    // seu código aqui
}
console.timeEnd('teste');
```

Nesse caso, seu código vai rodar 10000 vezes e no final você fica sabendo quanto tempo passou. Muito útil para comparar códigos para saber qual é o mais eficiente, p. ex:

```
console.time('teste1');
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    $('#painel .lista');
}
console.timeEnd('teste1');


console.time('teste2');
for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    $('#painel').find('.lista');
}
console.timeEnd('teste2');
```

Nesse exemplo acima, você descobre qual trecho é o mais eficiente: `$('#painel .lista')` ou `$('#painel').find('.lista')`, usando jQuery.

---

Ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/55872/622